# Unable to load webadmin for Neo4j High Availability

Tags: neo4j

I have installed 3 instances of neo4j version 1.9.4 on a linux machine, in 3 different directories: `Neo4j01`, `neo4j02`, `neo4j03`.

I have updated the configuration files `neo4j.properties` and `neo4j-server.properties` as mentioned in the link (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/ha-setup-tutorial.html).

When I start all the neo4j instances one after the other, they are successfully installing, but after some time 2 of the 3 neo4j process/instances are automatically disappearing. I noticed it via `ps -aef | grep neo4j`.

When I checked console logs then i found below errors:

```
2013-11-12 16:37:32.512+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Checking store consistency with master
2013-11-12 16:37:33.174+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Store is consistent
2013-11-12 16:37:33.176+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Catching up with master
2013-11-12 16:37:33.276+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Now consistent with master
2013-11-12 16:37:34.442+0000 INFO  [Cluster] ServerId 2, successfully moved to slave for master ha://localhost.localdomain:6363?serverId=1
2013-11-12 16:37:34.689+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Instance 1 is available as backup at backup://localhost.localdomain:6366
2013-11-12 16:37:34.798+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Instance 2 (this server) is available as slave at ha://localhost.localdomain:6364?serverId=2
2013-11-12 16:37:35.036+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Database available for write transactions
2013-11-12 16:37:35.360+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully started database
2013-11-12 16:37:36.079+0000 INFO  [API] Starting HTTP on port :7474 with 10 threads available
2013-11-12 16:37:40.596+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Instance 3 has failed
2013-11-12 16:37:43.654+0000 INFO  [API] Enabling HTTPS on port :7473
2013-11-12 16:38:01.081+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted REST API at: /db/manage/
2013-11-12 16:38:01.158+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted discovery module at [/]
2013-11-12 16:38:02.375+0000 INFO  [API] Loaded server plugin "CypherPlugin"
2013-11-12 16:38:02.449+0000 INFO  [API] Loaded server plugin "GremlinPlugin"
2013-11-12 16:38:02.462+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted REST API at [/db/data/]
2013-11-12 16:38:02.534+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted management API at [/db/manage/]
2013-11-12 16:38:03.568+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted webadmin at [/webadmin]
2013-11-12 16:38:06.189+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
2013-11-12 16:38:30.844+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474], reason [org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.net.BindException: Address already in use, java.net.BindException: Address already in use]]
2013-11-12 16:38:30.880+0000 DEBUG [API] org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.net.BindException: Address already in use, java.net.BindException: Address already in use]
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86) [neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49) [neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mortbay.util.MultiException[java.net.BindException: Address already in use, java.net.BindException: Address already in use]
        at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty6WebServer.startJetty(Jetty6WebServer.java:334) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty6WebServer.start(Jetty6WebServer.java:154) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startWebServer(AbstractNeoServer.java:344) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:187) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        ... 2 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.mortbay.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:188) ~[jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) ~[jetty-util-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
        at org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty6WebServer.startJetty(Jetty6WebServer.java:330) ~[neo4j-server-1.9.4.jar:1.9.4]
        ... 5 common frames omitted
2013-11-12 16:38:30.894+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

Now, only `neo4j01` process is running and `neo4j02` and `neo4j03` processes are disappeared. But even though `neo4j01` process is up and running I am unable to access the webadmin page at `http://htname:7474/webadmin/#/info/org.neo4j/High%20Availability/`.

Please, can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: What have you found when you have researched the problem reported in the log, the `java.net.BindException: Address already in use`?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/neo-technology/neo4j-enterprise-local-qa. This contains a rakefile that automates a local setup of 3 instances. Clone the repo locally, and use

```
rake setup_cluster start_cluster
```

to bring a locally running cluster online. Shutdown can be done via

```
rake stop_cluster
```

Find the configs in `machine[ABC]/conf/`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your time. Could you please let me know where i need to add the above lines? Below are the folders under conf and bin:

Comment: [kkhamru@redhat-linux conf]$ ls
arbiter.cfg           custom-logback.xml  log4j.properties        neo4j.properties         README.txt
arbiter-wrapper.conf  jmx.access          logging.properties      neo4j-server.properties  ssl
coord.cfg             jmx.password        neo4j-http-logging.xml  neo4j-wrapper.conf       windows-wrapper-logging.properties        ========
[kkhamru@redhat-linux conf]$ ls ../bin/
lib  neo4j  neo4j-arbiter  neo4j-backup  neo4j-coordinator  neo4j-coordinator-shell  neo4j-shell  org.neo4j.arbiter.plist  org.neo4j.server.plist  README.txt  utils

Comment: have you really cloned the repo mentioned above?